# how to create separate line charts for different groups in the same dataframe?

Tags: r, ggplot2, linechart

I have a dataset df and I want to generate separate line charts but in the same page for every unique ID having in the x-axis the Date and in y-axis the Values. The reason for that is that that the range of values for every ID is different and if I put it in the same graph I will not be able to see the lines for all the IDs.

```
dput(df)
structure(list(ID = c("F1", "F1", "F1", "F1", "F1", "F1", "F1", 
"F2", "F2", "F2", "F2", "F2", "F2", "F2", "F2", "F3", "F3", "F3", 
"F3", "F3", "F3", "F3", "F3", "F3", "F4", "F4", "F4", "F4", "F4", 
"F4", "F4", "F4"), Date = c("22/6/2021", "23/6/2021", "24/6/2021", 
"25/6/2021", "26/6/2021", "27/6/2021", "28/6/2021", "22/6/2021", 
"23/6/2021", "24/6/2021", "25/6/2021", "26/6/2021", "27/6/2021", 
"28/6/2021", "29/6/2021", "22/6/2021", "23/6/2021", "24/6/2021", 
"25/6/2021", "26/6/2021", "27/6/2021", "28/6/2021", "29/6/2021", 
"30/6/2021", "22/6/2021", "23/6/2021", "24/6/2021", "25/6/2021", 
"26/6/2021", "27/6/2021", "28/6/2021", "29/6/2021"), Values = c(9.6, 
9.8, 10.2, 9.8, 9.9, 9.9, 9.9, 1.2, 1.2, 1.8, 1.5, 1.5, 1.6, 
1.4, 1.1, 3266, 3256, 7044, 6868, 6556, 3405, 3410, 3980, 5567, 
59.4, 56, 52.8, 52.4, 55.5, 54, 61, 53.6)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-32L))
```

this is a line chart with the lines of all IDs. I am trying to create a different line chart for every ID

```
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = factor(Date), y = Values, color = ID)) +       
  geom_line(aes(group = ID)) + geom_point()
```

Comment: Are you looking for facets? `+ facet_wrap(~ID, scales = 'free')`

Comment: that was very helpful, i have one more question.  the IDs are in this order F1,F2,F3,F4 .  When I plot the plots are with this orderF1,F4,F2,F3. Do you know why is that? @RonakShah

Answer (score 1):

use `facet_wrap`

```
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = factor(Date), y = Values, color = ID)) +       
  geom_line(aes(group = ID)) + geom_point() + 
  facet_wrap(~ID, scales = 'free_y')
```

---

to create your own order

```
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = factor(Date), y = Values, color = ID)) +       
  geom_line(aes(group = ID)) + geom_point() + 
  facet_wrap(~factor(ID,
                     levels=c("F1", "F2", "F3", "F4")), 
             scales = 'free_y')
```

Comment: that was very helpful, i have one more question.  the IDs are in this order F1,F2,F3,F4 .  When I plot the plots are with this orderF1,F4,F2,F3. Do you know why is that? @dy_by

Comment: `facor` should help. omit `levels` to keep *alphabetical order*. added above.